# Which is better for building a game, Corona SDK or Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, device, coronasdk

I recently looked at Bubble Ball's website, and it says Built With Corona SDK. I've never heard of Corona, and, from what I read, it lets you create games for devices with very little code. I'm not convinced. Which should I go with? Xcode or Corona SDK?

EDIT:
To clarify, I would like to know which is better for building a good, solid iPhone game.

Comment: To do what? Make games for iOS? Xcode is an IDE and Corona SDK is an SDK. They cannot be compared. If your question is "Should I develop games using Corona SDK or OpenGL ES/Quartz/CoreAnimation/Etc", then please state accordingly.

Comment: This question is completely [subjective](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#ask). Please edit it, perhaps to ask about _specific_ features of an SDK.

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to use an off-the-shelf game engine to allow you to focus on your game rather than on the framework. There are many options out there to choose from. I have put together a [large list of iPhone game engines](http://mobilegameengines.com/iphone/game_engines) that might prove useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's really a matter of how much risk are you willing to take.

XCode may take longer, but you know it'll get accepted and new iOS versions won't completely hose it up.

Corona will write less code getting to 90%. That last 10% may be a real pain though. If Apple comes out with iOS XXX and everything breaks. You're waiting on Corona to update their SDK until you can update your app. Or if Apple releases a new feature, you'll wait for the Corona update before you can take advantage of it.

Personally, I'm a native XCode guy. These frameworks do have their place though.

Comment: Corona subscribers have access to Daily Builds, so if iOS XXX broke Corona apps, there would be a build to take care of that right away. Unless Apple came out with an iOS that broke EVERY app (not just Corona apps), they would also provide a way for everyone to fix their apps (ex. iOS 5 broke many apps) ... if one of those apps were the Corona engine, Ansca engineers would be able to fix it very easily and roll out the update via Daily Builds.

Comment: What happens when Corona goes out of business or their servers go offline?   The apps are built on THEIR servers.   Something to consider.  When you use services like this you are permanently married to the vendor.

Answer (score 29):

Which is better for creating a good, solid iPhone game?

That's not a question anybody can answer for you. What may be better for you isn't necessarily better for the next guy.

Last fall after more than two decades as a programmer I decided to learn Objective-C and Xcode and start making iPhone apps. After a few weeks going through tutorials in a couple books and slowly getting up to speed I stumbled across Corona SDK.

I was pissed.

Because I don't want to CODE, I want to write games. And here was an SDK, that, while still required coding, cut such a huge chunk off the learning curve that for me and what I wanted to do it made perfect sense. (I was pissed that I'd "wasted" time because Ansca Mobile didn't do enough advertising for me to know about Corona SDK ahead of that time.)

The games I want to write are 2D puzzle games, adventure/RPG, and arcade games. If you want to do something that requires all the power you can pull from the device you'll probably NOT want to use Corona -- you give up some power in exchange for faster/easier development.

Corona SDK uses Lua as the language that ties it all together and even if you have no experience with it, Lua is pretty easy to pick up.

With Xcode/Obj-C you can do anything your heart desires -- with Corona SDK you are limited to what it has available. For example, in the past, while AdMob could be used in Corona-based apps, iAds could not. Enabling OpenFeint is a 1-liner, but GameCenter wasn't available except via OpenFeint.

Those two examples are things I expect Corona to support sooner rather than later. Ansca Mobile has been very good about releasing regular updates with new functionality and better performance.

So while there are some limitations with a tool like Corona SDK, there are advantages you just don't get when you "roll your own."

Hard-core racing games? First-person shooters? Anything 3-D based? Corona SDK is probably not for you.

But most other game genres? I wouldn't use anything else but Corona SDK.

Yes, I am a fanboi.

Jay

Answer (score 11):

I've spent many, many years working in the Java EE world where we have 1001 APIs, builders, frameworks and GUI driven tools that all claim to accelerate the development process. Some do, some don't and some are more trouble than they are worth. There are several things to understand before choosing to go down this route.

Firstly, yes these tools get you up and running fast. But there is a hidden cost. You are severely limited by the facilities that the tool provides. Its not unusual that you will want to do something the tool cannot do or support. Then you have a problem - do you abandon the tool and start from scratch? do you try to hack it? or do you put everything on hold until the tool updates?

Secondly there's the bug aspect. Every time you include something extra, you also include any bugs or poor design decisions behind it. For example I once used an API that pro-ported to simplify using the Lucene search engine in a Java application. It did, but a very poorly design implementation meant that we then waste two days figuring out it has issues that were unresolvable. We then lost another 2 days whilst we waiting for the author to tell us he wasn't going to fix it. So we lost around a week in time total before we ripped it out. Much more than if we had just manually written the code necessary to include Lucene.

Then there's @Rexeisen's point about the delays in getting new features - a good point to keep in mind.

This all doesn't mean that external APIs and tools are to be avoided, I use quite a few myself. But I'm pretty choosy about them. How well supported are they? how flexible are they? can they be extended? how hard would it be to rip them out? what are their limits? are they really going to help me or am I just swapping one set of issues for another? All these questions are important before you start using them in anger.

So what I'm trying to say is don't do what I've seen so many do - find something shiny and new with a big sales blurb and just leap in with it thinking it will save the world. They usually don't. Take a hard look first and then decide if you want to give it a try.

Finally, and I cannot emphasis this enough - there is no substitute for knowing the nuts and bolts of developing something from scratch.

Comment: What does your answer have to do with Corona or Lua, or anything game-related?

Comment: This answer is related because Corona SDK offers a specific Lua API which is limited, compared to the full API accessible through Objective-C. The answer highlights some of the problems that this can lead to, through the example of Java APIs.

Answer (score 5):

First off, it depends what kind of game you want to make. This choice is only relevant for 2D games since that's the only sort of game Corona supports. If you want to do a 3D game then look elsewhere (eg. Unity.)

Second, by "XCode" I'm going to interpret your question to mean "cocos2D" because I'm hard-pressed to think of a reason why you wouldn't use cocos2D if you are going the route of programming in Objective-C.

That said...

cocos2D is an awesome framework and the best one to use if you need the flexibility of a native library and/or absolutely need features not supported in Corona. It is not a case of Objective-C or cocos2D; cocos2D is a library you use through XCode and Objective-C.

Corona is amazingly productive and the best tool to use if your project can be executed within the feature set. And note that trimming some less critical features is not a bad tradeoff at all because the massively accelerated development process (like 10x, seriously) is very valuable. Even without considering any other shortcuts (and there are a number,) the fact that you're programming in Lua instead of Objective-C makes development an order of magnitude faster.

---

The upshot is that I am planning to use Corona for my current and upcoming projects, but am glad I have cocos2D to turn to if I need it.